# Magento2 make simple afterSave action plugin of custom module

Tags: magento2.2, plugin, save, admin-controller

I am trying to create afterSave plugin for my admin form save action controller of my custom module. The purpose of this is to save some data into second table once all data completely save in first table.

Here is my di.xml file code :

```
<type name="Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Options\Save">
    <plugin name="save_option_label" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\OptionlabelSave" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

I have also created OptionlabelSave.php file inside \Plugin\ directory.

Here is the code :

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin;

/**
 * Class OptionlabelSave
 * @package Namespace\Module\Plugin
 */
class OptionlabelSave
{
    public function afterSave(Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Options\Save $subject, $result) {
        echo 'test save'; exit;

        return $result;
    }
}
```

However, when I click on save button in admin edit form I am not getting 'test save' printed on my screen. Am I missing anything here?

Please help. That would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please add Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Options\Save code here?

Comment: Hello @RutveeSojitra. That is normal save data code using model nothing exceptional. I think I came to know from some googling that we can't use plugin actions after,around and before  for Controller. It can be use for model. For controller we need to use Preference that is actually overwrite. Is it true?

Comment: No, we can do also in controller
please refer for more https://www.mageplaza.com/how-use-plugin-preference-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-magento-2.html

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Thanks for the reference. I will refer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution myself. Earlier, I have used **afterSave()** method inside plugin file. Instead, we need to use either **afterExecute()** or **aroundExecute()** depending upon the type of requirement.

That's it!

Thanks,